# Try with resources using a connection pool and single connection

Tags: java, try-catch

During a code review I found the following code snippet:

```
try (
   Connection con = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder()
    .build(configuration)
    .buildFactory()
    .openSession()
    .getConnection()
){
   // do stuff here with 'con' and not close anything   
}
```

Session, Connection, SqlSessionFactory are iBatis implementations, but the questions is interested in any 'stacked' implementation of the Closable interface.

I am assuming 'try with resources' closes the resource, that is instantiated - ***con*** in this case. Normally you'd close session and connection each individually. If using the above code the ***close()*** method will just be called on ***con*** object, so session is not explicitly called and will rely on the garbage collection?

Will the code be any better using:

```
try (
   Session session = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder()
    .build(configuration)
    .buildFactory()
    .openSession(); 
   Connection con = session.getConnection();
){
   // do stuff here with 'con' and not close anything
}
```

The latter approach seems cleaner in my eyes as it should call ***close()*** correctly. Or is my interpretation wrong and just boilerplate code?

Comment: This might be a better question for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than for StackOverflow. For my part, I think your idea is correct, and this is probably something you should call out and change in the code review - this `try` syntax is allowed for precisely this reason, after all.

Comment: I think it's suited here ok as it's more a language feature or language mechanics question than code polishing. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct, try-with-resources will close only resources explicitly declared in resources block.

However, in most cases the first approach will work as well. That is because usually when some `Closeable` uses another `Closeable`, it will try to close it inside of its `close()` method. This mechanism doesn't have anything to do with the garbage collector tho (which would just remove an object without releasing the resource).

Other than the situation where a `Closeable` wouldn't close its resources, there could be other sources of resources leak in the first approach as well. Consider a following case:

```
try(BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(
                                            new FileInputStream("file.txt"))
)
```

In this example, `FileInputStream` will be created first. Just then it will be passed into a contructor of `BufferedInputStream`. What would happen when an exception occurs during creation of `BufferedInputStream`? `FileInputStream` won't ever be closed.
On the other hand, when you declare those as two separate resources like so:

```
try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(input)
)
```

Java itself will make sure that both of the resources will be closed. The following is stated in [JSL - 14.20.3.1. Basic try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1) :

> In a basic try-with-resources statement that manages multiple resources:
>
> If the initialization of a resource completes abruptly because of a
> throw of a value V, then:
>
> If the automatic closings of all successfully initialized resources
> (possibly zero) complete normally, then the try-with-resources
> statement completes abruptly because of a throw of the value V.

There are probably more cases that might cause resource leak as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the example that is an even better fit to what I was referring to!